# jquery deferred and promise in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is something wrong. All functions should be called synchronously. Could anyone give me a hint? I think that is an error in the for loop
Here is my code:

```
  var radioValues = msg.options;
  var cn = gotoReport()
   .then(clickReport)
   .then(clickReportFake)
   .then(clickNext);

   for (var i = 0; i < radioValues.length; i++){
       cn = cn.then(clickOption(radioValues[i])).then(clickNext);
   }
   cn.then(clickSendToFacebook).then(clickFinish);  


//all called functions look like that 
  function clickNext(){
        return process(function(){
            console.log("clickNext");
            var next = $('button:contains("Weiter")');
             $(next).click();
        },3000);
    }   

function process(action, ms) {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      timer = setInterval(function() {
        deferred.notify();
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function() {
         clearInterval(timer);
         action();
         deferred.resolve();
      }, ms);

//    return deferred;    
      return deferred.promise();
    }


function sleep(ms)
{
    return(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {        
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, ms);        
    }));    
}
```

Here is the output

```
gotoReport
clickOption=option3
clickReport
clickReportFake
clickNext
clickNext
clickSendToFacebook
clickFinish
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Also take a look at how to create a [mcve]. If you want to call things synchronously, I'm not sure why you're using `setTimeout`, `Deferred`s, or `Promise`s, as they are all used for asynchronous code.

Comment: I use the settimeout function to make a sleep between the function calls.

Comment: this is not the complete code. functions are missing and also where do you call `sleep()` ?

Comment: oh sorry the sleep function is wrong here. This function can be ignored. ;-)

Comment: *"All functions should be called synchronously."*: why do you think that? They are not, since the `setTimeout` callback is invoked asynchronously.

Comment: i want all functions called synchronously. The "then" call make it synchronously. But there is something wrong in the for loop that it was not synchronously anymore.

Comment: *"The "then" call make it synchronously."*: no. `then` was invented to make asynchronous code easier to manage, not to make it synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major issue is here:

```
cn.then(clickOption(radioValues[i]))
```

You are not *passing* the `clickOption` function as argument to `then` -- you are *invoking* it. Instead do:

```
cn.then(clickOption.bind(null, radioValues[i]))
```